# Set message inside the add dialog in jqgrid if error occurs

Tags: error-handling, jqgrid, dialog, addition

I am returning the following from my action (asp mvc) if error occurs upon adding the record to jqgrid

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "item not found");
```

It's all great but the message displayed inside the add dialog is

```
"error Status: 'Workorder not found'. Error code: 400"
```

Is there any way to just show the "Item not found" message only?

It looks like the js never goes to afterSubmit routine in add options. Any way to gain the control and make sure that only the actual error message shows? Something like onError option would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `errorTextFormat` callback of form editing or `jqGridAddEditErrorTextFormat` event of jqGrid to control the format of the text from the error message. The first parameter of `errorTextFormat` callback (or the second parameter of `jqGridAddEditErrorTextFormat`) is `jqXHR` Object which is superset of `XMLHttpRequest`. The `responseText` property of the parameter is the text of the response body.

Moreover you should not use `HttpStatusCodeResult` for error description. Instead of that you should place **the error description in the body of HTTP response**. You can use `WebFaultException` for example to do this:

```cs
return throw new WebFaultException<string> (
                     "item not found",
                     HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); // 400
```

By the way the HTTP status code 404 (`HttpStatusCode.NotFound`) seems me more corresponds to the error `"item not found"`.